# jquery animate .css

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a script:

```
$('#hfont1').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css({"color":"#efbe5c","font-size":"52pt"}); //mouseover
    }, 
    function() {
        $(this).css({"color":"#e8a010","font-size":"48pt"}); // mouseout
    }
);
```

how can i animate it or slow it down, so it wont be instant ?

Comment: use the jQuery animate function: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Just use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) instead of [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) (with a duration if you want), like this:

```
$('#hfont1').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({"color":"#efbe5c","font-size":"52pt"}, 1000);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({"color":"#e8a010","font-size":"48pt"}, 1000);
});
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/GELTP/).  Note though, you need either the [jQuery color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color), or [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) included to animate the color.  In the above, the duration is 1000ms, you can change it, or just leave it off for the default 400ms duration.

Comment: It would be cool if SO had realtime answer monitoring to watch people type, but it would be a huge resource hog ;)

Comment: You could also use .filter(':not(:animated)') to check that the animation has finished running before executing again.

A nice example can be found here: http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/

Comment: You might also want to include a `.stop()` before the animate part, else you get a long durating flangy effect when moving your mouse accross the element fast a couple of times. Here is the fiddle with that added http://jsfiddle.net/GELTP/1586/

Answer (score 8):

You could opt for a pure CSS solution:

```
#hfont1 {
    transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color 1s ease-in-out; /* FF 4 */
    -webkit-transition: color 1s ease-in-out; /* Safari & Chrome */
    -o-transition: color 1s ease-in-out; /* Opera */
}
```

Comment: ...forgot to add the delay at the end, e.g. 'transition: color 1s ease-in-out 2s;', adding a 2 second delay to the animation.

Answer (score 0):

The example from jQuery's website animates size AND font but you could easily modify it to fit your needs

```
$("#go").click(function(){
  $("#block").animate({ 
    width: "70%",
    opacity: 0.4,
    marginLeft: "0.6in",
    fontSize: "3em", 
    borderWidth: "10px"
  }, 1500 );
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

You can actually still use ".css" and apply css transitions to the div being affected. So continue using ".css" and add the below styles to your stylesheet for "#hfont1". Since ".css" allows for a lot more properties than ".animate", this is always my preferred method.

```
#hfont1 {
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s;
    transition: width 0.4s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are needing to use CSS with the jQuery `.animate()` function, you can use set the duration.

```
$("#my_image").css({
    'left':'1000px',
    6000, ''
});
```

We have the duration property set to 6000.

This will set the time in thousandth of seconds: 6 seconds.

After the duration our next property "easing" changes how our CSS happens.

We have our positioning set to absolute.

There are two default ones to the absolute function: 'linear' and 'swing'.

In this example I am using linear.

It allows for it to use a even pace.

The other 'swing' allows for a exponential speed increase.

There are a bunch of really cool properties to use with animate like bounce, etc.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my_image").css({
        'height': '100px',
        'width':'100px',
        'background-color':'#0000EE',
        'position':'absolute'
    });// property than value

    $("#my_image").animate({
        'left':'1000px'
    },6000, 'linear', function(){
        alert("Done Animating");
    });
});
```