# jquery .animate() not animating

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make a border fade in around an element.

Following the answer on: [jquery animate .css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347104/jquery-animate-css), I used the `.animate()` jquery function and followed the tutorial [on the jquery site](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

However, I cannot get it to work. Here is my code on jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/epojaw/2
Hovering on the text should fade in the border around it, but instead, it just appears suddenly.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a fade in effect by changing the width of the border from 0px to 1px. I assume the step size is 1px, so yes it appears immediately.

Instead you could try to create a fade in using the border color, eg from white to red. Then jQuery is able to have more steps and your effect works better.

Comment: would I change borderColor? and would it be possible to do borderColor:rgba(x,x,x,0)?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813493/jquery-animate-border-color-on-hover for more information on animating the border color.

Comment: @KevinDuke I just tested it and it does not.  You could manually create your own though with the step function theoretically.

Comment: Indeed, according to the question I provided you need to use `borderTopColor` (and the other 3) for animation. One of the answers suggest using a plugin which does this for you.

Comment: borderTopColor doesn't work, and according to http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/ it's a bug in jquery

Comment: Well use that plugin that fixes the bug :)

Answer (score 1):

it is because the border only animates the width of the border 1 by 1.

if you put a border-width of 10px it animates: http://jsbin.com/utiwoy/3